# Can I create a new branch on master when working on another branch?

Tags: git

I can't seem to find any information regarding this, here is the scenario:

I'm working on a feature branch.  A bug gets reported.  So I switch to my master branch then create a new branch by checkout with the -b switch

```
git checkout -b bugbranch
```

What happens if I issue the command on a branch other than master?  Will it create a new branch under master or create a branch off of the other branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new branch is created from the current branch you are on

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was trying to determine.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
git branch branchname startpoint
```

This will create a new branch with name `branchname` and starting point at `startpoint`. For more information, consult `git branch --help`.

Comment: Thaks for the info.  I read the help and it seems that your suggestion works, but does not switch the working tree. Is that correct?